# Setup Required to Run TestCafe tests on Safari browser

Tags: testing, safari, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm attempting to execute a TestCafe suite on locally installed Safari. I have previously executed the tests on chrome, chrome:headless, firefox, and firefox:headless. When running the command `testcafe --list-browsers` to retrieve my list of installed browsers, I receive the following:

```
testcafe --list-browsers
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
firefox
chrome
safari
```

When I execute a simple test via command line, `testcafe safari path/to/tests/`, the Safari browser will launch, but no navigation takes place. I remain on the launch window (showing my favorites and recently visited pages). 
When the same command is executed for a different browser (say, `testcafe chrome path/to/tests/`), the tests are executed in the local browser.

Am I missing something that is required to get Safari up and running with TestCafe? I'm using TestCafe version `1.6.1`. I'm not seeing any additional setup mentioned on the TestCafe documentation...

Comment: There are no special settings for Safari. I suggest you try the latest TestCafe version.

Comment: I'm unable to use the latest version of TestCafe due to Node restrictions with the project. Looking through the documentation related to post-1.6.1 releases, there was nothing indicating the Safari setup changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by disabling all uses of `TestCafe Browser Tools` in `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Automation`. On my subsequent execution, I was prompted to allow TestCafe Browser Tools for Safari. After accepting the prompt, the tests ran as expected.

I also had deleted my `node_modules` directory and reinstalled dependencies, although I'm skeptical if that helped.